# Красивый вывод стоимости товара

Tags: php

Есть товар, его стоимость 55.500 , в базе сумма записана так: `55500` .
вопрос. каким образом сделать вывод суммы вида **55.500** , не изменяя запись о сумме в базе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number_format` — Форматирует число с разделением групп

```
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )

string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

Функция принимает один, два или четыре аргумента (не три):

Если передан только один аргумент, number будет отформатирован без дробной части, но с запятой (",") между каждыми тремя цифрами.

Если переданы два аргумента, number будет отформатирован с decimals знаками после точки (".") и с запятой (",") между каждыми тремя цифрами.

Если переданы все четыре аргумента, number будет отформатирован с decimals знаками после точки и с разделителем между между каждыми тремя цифрами, при этом в качестве десятичной точки будет использован dec_point, а в качестве разделителя групп - thousands_sep.

**[источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)**

Вам нужен `thousands_sep`

Пример:

```
$num = 55000;

echo number_format($num, 0, '', '.');
```

Comment: не совсем понятно что-то)

Comment: не могли бы вы продемонстрировать преобразование числа с точками. предположим число берем из переменной `$chislo`

Comment: спасибо большое. все понял

Comment: @Денис сделал.... вам нужно четвертый параметр применять